# OrientDB - filter selected vertices by other vertices connected to them

Tags: sql, filtering, server-side, orientdb

I'm not an OrientDB profi, so maybe my question will sound dumb; but I didn't find any answers in docs or on the Net.

[This is a sample of a data structure that I have:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXY6O.png)
I want to find all of the beavers, that have blue eyes, and they're happy and they know it.

I do manage to select the eye color and the happiness state with out() function - something like

```
SELECT out('has').eyeColors, out('is').happinessState FROM beavers
```

But how do I filter by those connected vertices? I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM beavers WHERE out('has').eyeColors = 'blue' AND out('is').happinessState = 'happy and knows it'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM beavers WHERE (SELECT out('has').eyeColors FROM beavers) = 'blue' AND (SELECT out('is').happinessState FROM beavers) = 'happy and knows it'
```

but both of the query types tend to return empty results.

So - how can I achieve such a selection?

*I run Community Edition, v. 2.1.11, and do all of this in server-side JS function.

Thanks,
Gregory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the WHERE condition you need to use the `CONTAINS` word because the `out()` - so for `in()` and `both()` - returns a list.

eg

```
select from Beaver where out('has').eyeColors contains "Blue" and out("iss").happinessState contains "happy and knows it"
```

You can verify whether it returns a list or not by selecting it:

```
select out('has').eyeColors from Beaver
```

---

PS

I see that you're using an edge class called `is` that, I think, it's not allowed since it is a private word.

---

Hope it helps. Ivan

---

**UPDATE**

```
select name from Children
let $a=(select from Beaver where in('has').@rid contains $parent.$current.@rid and out('has').eyeColor contains "Blue" and out("iss").happinessState contains "happy and knows it")
where $a.size() > 0
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks Ivan :)
Additional connected question - can I use such a query in subquery?

Comment: For example, when adding an additional category Children, that are connected with Has edge to Beavers, and want to retrieve Children, that Has Beavers, that Has Blue Eyes and Are Happy And They Know It (thank you for your remark about classes names, but in this case all of the names are dummy, just to make the logic more clear). Or maybe, there are more perfomant ways to achieve this in JS serverside function?

Comment: well, that is slightly more complex. I'm gonna modify my answer